# Setting the text factory for SQLite in Twisted

Tags: sqlite, twisted

I am trying to store binary data in a sqlite database using the Twisted adbapi. However, when I run a query to store the data, I get an error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

After googling a bit, I found the answer for a normal sqlite connection:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(...)
con.text_factory = str
```

However, I can't find an equivalent setting to use with a twisted adbapi sqlite connection:

```
dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool("sqlite3", "data.db", check_same_thread=False)
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. In order to make changes to the connection after it opens, you have to use the [`cp_openfun`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionPool.html) parameter for the ConnectionPool. The following code worked:

```
def set_text_factory(conn):
    conn.text_factory = str

dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool("sqlite3", "data.db", check_same_thread=False,
    cp_openfun=set_text_factory)
```

Comment: Glad you worked it out for yourself, thanks for following up :)